# Get nearest datetime from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I want to join table 1 with table 2 with nearest time table 1 X table 2.

table 1:

```
datetime 1      
-----------------------
2016-01-12 10:00:00
```

table 2:

```
datetime 2
-----------------------
2016-01-12 10:40:00
2016-01-12 09:30:00
2016-01-12 12:00:00
```

the nearest time is "2016-01-12 09:30:00" from datetime 1 - table 1...

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2
WHERE datetime_1 > now();
```

Comment: This question requires more detail and explanation - preferably in the question itself. What language(s) are you working in for instance?

Comment: Is the nearest always smaller then the one in table1? Or is it possible that it could e.g. be `10:05:00`? Also: do you have the possibility to upgrade to a more recent Postgres version?

Comment: `ORDER BY` the other table on date `WHERE otherTableDate < yourDate` and pick the first result (limit 1).